# Grafana issue while adding datasource of prometheus

Tags: java, spring-boot, grafana, prometheus

When i use `http://127.0.0.1:8080/myprometheus` as URL in my datasource of **garafana** , I encounter with the following issue:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Answer (score 0):

The Prometheus link to be given there should be 9090, as that is where Prometheus listens to by default. You should be publishing to a different port and this port is specified in the Prometheus.yml file as below:
static_configs:
    - targets: ['ServerDetails:PortNumber']

Try putting the datasource link as http://127.0.0.1:9090

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you for help. Prometheus scraps the metrics on port 9090 by default. But I made my application and directed it metrics on port localhost:8080 and added it's specification in prometheus.yml. So now my application metrics are scraped on http://localhost:8080/myprometheus.    Now I want to add this in URL of datasource in garfana.

Comment: Also, try using a different port, other than 8080 as some other application might be using the same port.

Comment: Yes, you are pushing via your application to 8080 and gave that port in Prometheus.yml. In prometheus, you added it under static_configs, correct? In that case it is just the port from which Prometheus reads data. In order to make that data available to Grafana, you need to specify the Prometheus port - 9090. Give it a try

Comment: - job_name: 'spring-actuator'
    metrics_path: '/myprometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
     - targets: ['localhost:8080']
This is what I've mentioned in prometheus.yml

Comment: I did tried http://127.0.0.1:9090 as url in grafana but it's fetching metrics of promethues /metrics by default.   I want to scarp metrics of my application which is on port 8080

Comment: Please mark it as an answer if it resolved the issue.